# Servlet Database URL

Tags: java, mysql, database, servlets

I'm trying to have a servlet to connect and interact with a database. I'm very new at this topic, so there probably are a couple of big issues, but the main problem I'm stuck at is how to get the database URL.

This is the servlet (I'm trying to keep it as light as possible)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class qaServlet extends HttpServlet{
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
                String firstName = request.getParameter("question");
                response.setContentType("text/html");
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/qaDatabase", "root", ""); 
//^HOW DO I GET THE RIGHT URL?^

                    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into faq values('1','question','sì');");
                    int i = ps.executeUpdate();
                }
                catch (Exception e2) {
                    System.out.println(e2);
                }
                out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The URL looks good, as far as your database is named `qaDatabase` and mysql engine runs on the same machine as the servlet engine. Change `System.out.println(e2);` to `e2.printStackTrace();` and add the stack trace to your question.

Comment: Thank you!
I did it and now it gives me an error in the Class.forName line:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

I do have loaded the jdbc connector's JAR in the library though..

Comment: The JAR file with JDBC driver **must** be either in `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your application, or in Tomcat's `lib` folder. If you are still developing, have you re-published your project?

Comment: That fixed that up, I managed to have the interact!

I would like to vote yours as the actual answer, how do I do that with comments?

Comment: I have added a summarizing answer, so you can vote for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is better to use `e2.printStackTrace();` instead of `System.out.println(e2);` when debugging.

Second, as the exception has shown, the actual problem was missing JAR file with JDBC driver, which has to be either in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your application, or in Tomcat's `lib` folder.

When developing, don't forget to republish your project after adding the driver's JAR file.